# How to add post to pending list of a group using facebook api

Tags: reactjs, facebook-graph-api, facebook-javascript-sdk

I'm building a web app where users can post to a Facebook group and content of the group is displayed in the app. I want the users of app to create posts in the app so that those posts are sent to the pending posts list of that group and then group admins can approve posts. However, I didn't find any way to accomplish this in Facebook API documentation. Can someone help me with how to accomplish this task? Any helpful tip is highly appreciated.

Comment: You can not post in the name of a user any more via API.

Comment: But I saw in the api docs that this can done with proper permission. see https://developers.facebook.com/docs/groups-api/#requirements. In my app, users are required to login with Facebook. Therefore, I dont think its not possible

Comment: Oh, yes, for groups it is still possible, the rest was removed (posting on personal profiles or pages.) But there is no way to make these posts pending while posting, you can only specify the message and a link, those are the only two parameters. Whether new posts are considered pending and need approval, is a group settings thing.